# Vuex Asynchronous Update doesn't change view

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vuejs2, updating, vuex

I have an VUEX store with an object with the following state

`state: {
        owner: 0,
        allCats: [],
        availableCats: [],
        activeCat: null,
        rooms: []
    }`.

This mutation is meant to add chat-messages to one of the cats in `allCats`

```js
addMessage: function(state, messageData) {

            let index = state.allCats.indexOf(messageData.cat);

            // if no messages are available initialize array
            if(!state.allCats[index].messages) {
                state.allCats[index].messages = [];
            }

            state.allCats[index].messages.push({
                text: messageData.message,
                type: messageData.type
            });
        }
```

When I call trigger this immediately on an event, everything works fine. However when I load some asynchronous data first and then trigger the mutation in `then()` the state is changed, but view is not updated.

Can anyone explain to me why I get this behaviour and how I can fix it?
Thanks!

PS: The repo can be view at https://github.com/sarahschuetz/IM531_ProjectT1

---

SOLUTION:

I was able to solve the problem by initialising the `message[]` immediately when loading the cats from the database instead of only initialising it with the first message.

Comment: It seems a problem with reactivity. Your `messages` array isn't acknowledge by Vue. See: [Reactivity In Depth](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
I already read the article you mentioned, but I can't understand why the mutation would work when invoked directly (without loading asynchronous data)..
is there any way to trigger a view update after the state was changed?

Comment: Never mind, I was able to figure out the solution. It was reactivity after all and the reason it was working one time but not the other was, that in one case I altered another state additionally which was triggering the rerendering of the view. Thanks for your help!